# Using ProgressBar in WPF, Simple Application

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have been trying to make sense of this article http://bensprogrammingwork.blogspot.com/2012/01/progressbar-in-wpf.html

I have the following code on my `Button_Click` event:

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\cle1394\\Desktop\\Apple Foreign Tax Payment Sample Layout Proposed - Sample Data.xlsx");

ConsoleApplication2.Program.ExcelData data = ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData(existingFile);
```

The `GetExcelData()` method takes a few minutes to complete, so I would like to show a progress bar to indicate the estimated time until completion.

However, I don't know how to apply the methods in the tutorial above to my code below for `GetExcelData()`:

```
public static ExcelData GetExcelData(FileInfo file)
{
    ExcelData data = new ExcelData();
    data.Countries = new List<Country>();

    using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
        // get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

        List<string> countryNames = new List<string> 
        { 
            "Australia"/*,
            "China - Beijing",
            "China - Shanghai",
            "Hong Kong",
            "Hungary",
            "Ireland",
            "Spain",
            "United Kingdom"*/
        };

        List<string> monthNames = new List<string>
        {
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        };

        foreach (string name in countryNames)
        {
            Country country = new Country();

            Console.WriteLine(name);

            country.Name = name;
            country.Months = new List<Month>();

            foreach (string _name in monthNames)
            {
                country.Months.Add(GetMonthDataRows(_name, GetMonth(_name, GetCountry(name, worksheet), worksheet), worksheet));
            }

            country.Totals = GetTotals(country);

            data.Countries.Add(country);

            // this is where I would like to update the progressbar

        }

    } // the using statement calls Dispose() which closes the package.

    return data;
}
```

I would like to update the progressbar in the foreach loop above.  Can someone show me an example how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your questions

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429256/wpf-progressbar

Comment: @bhs I have seen that but I am still not sure how to do this.  I would appreciate a simple example.  Thanks.

Comment: BackgroudWorker ReportsProgress

Comment: @Blam I understand the concept but don't know how to apply it.  Could you please show me an example using my code above?

Comment: There is a great example in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: here is the example http://bensprogrammingwork.blogspot.in/2012/01/progressbar-in-wpf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the the following code to the bw_dowork method in the tutorial and it should work.

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\cle1394\\Desktop\\Apple Foreign Tax Payment     Sample Layout Proposed - Sample Data.xlsx");

ConsoleApplication2.Program.ExcelData data =  ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData(existingFile);
```

so, what they are doing is that onStart_click they they start the background async task, that is where you need to write what you are currently doing in the onClick method.

Comment: Thanks, Sayed.  But I have to update the `_worker.ReportProgress(i);` from within `ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData()` and I am not sure how.

Comment: I am not sure if it would work but try passing the worker as a parameter to the GetExcelData,so that you get a reference to the worker and then try calling the worker.ReportProgress method inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing in WPF but I was wanting to show update messages in a List without blocking the UI thread [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263597/can-a-long-running-method-and-a-working-dialog-be-run-together-using-the-ta). You could replace the List in this example with a message. Sorry, don't have time to write a simplified version of it just now.

Answer (score 1):

In the article, you will see a `BackgroundWorker` object. Firstly, read about the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) on MSDN.

This object provides an easy way to perform long running actions in a separate thread. It is essential that you perform long running actions on a thread separate from the UI thread if you don't want your UI to lock up whilst the action is executing. It is irrelevant whether you use a Console application or not for this.

In the article, you will also see a `ProgressChangedEventHandler` which is set to a method called `bw_ProgressChanged` in the constructor. This `bw_ProgressChanged` method will be **called on the UI thread** so this is where you can access your UI elements, namely, your `ProgressBar` object.

Look now at the `bw_DoWork` method... this is where you... do the work (the long running action) on the other thread (created by the `BackgroundWorker`). Now, note the line where the `BackgroundWorkwer` is created from the `sender` parameter... this is essential because you need to use that object to call the `bw_ProgressChanged` method from the other thread. This is done using the `ReportProgress` method of the `BackgroundWorkwer` class.

The value that you pass as the progress value is up to you, but must be between the minimum and maximum values that you set in your `ProgressBar` control. The idea is that you regularly pass a value that increases each time you do a bit of work and ends at the value that you set your `ProgressBar.Maximum` to.

So the only connection to your example above is the `GetExcelData()` method which you would put in your `DoWork` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  How do I call `_worker.ReportProgress(i);` from my `ConsoleApplication2.Program.GetExcelData()` method?

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to move the code in your `GetExcelData()` method into the `DoWork` method, replacing the `Thread.Sleep` line. Then you could move the call to `_worker.ReportProgress(i)` inside your `foreach` loop perhaps? The rest is for you to work out. :)

Comment: I figured that but I was hoping there would be a more OOP approach.

Comment: There is, but it's more complicated and I don't really have enough time to explain it all to you. Basically, you could create a new class, put your `GetExcelData()` method in there along with a custom `delegate`. In the `DoWork` method, create a new instance of your new class and set up a local handler for the delegate. Either the delegate or the class constructor would need to take a parameter of type `BackgroundWorker` so that you can react when the `delegate` is called from the `GetExcelData()` method by calling `_worker.ReportProgress(i)`... it just adds one level of abstraction.